# How to deep copy int in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, deep-copy

As a self-taught programmer, I recently came to know about deep/shallow copying when working with singleton arrays and dictionaries. Today I found out another problem and that is even int values requires deep copying (?). Let me illustrate the problem:

```
[[MyData singleton] car].id = -10;
int carId = [[MyData singleton] car].id;
carId = abs(carId);
NSLog(@"%d", carId);

Log says

-10.

I would expect it to be 10 but no.
```

So how do I go about deep copying this value? I tried

```
int newCarId = abs(carId);
```

But still not working. Help.

Comment: int is primitive. It is always copy/pass by value

Comment: That's what i thought. Maybe something else im missing.

Comment: http://ideone.com/RLVA48  Prints 10.

Comment: Ok found out what the problem was. Nothing to do with deep copying. The problem was out of range issue that gives me a negative number. changing the type to long long solves the problem. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I create a test APP to test it but can't reappear your problem, my code:

`@interface DingTest : NSObject`

`@property (nonatomic, assign) int testValue;`

`@end`

`@implementation DingTest`
`@end`

`@interface AppDelegate ()`
`@end`

`@implementation AppDelegate`

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

```
DingTest *testClass = [[DingTest alloc]init];
testClass.testValue = -2;

int b = testClass.testValue;
b = abs(testClass.testValue);
NSLog(@"%d", testClass.testValue);
NSLog(@"%d", b);
NSLog(@"%d", abs(testClass.testValue));
NSLog(@"%d", abs(b));

return YES;
```

`}`

My log:
-2
2
2
2

you can just copy & paste it to test it

did you use **'assign'** or other keywords?

Comment: I upvoted this because of your effort to help me. Turns out the problem was due to something else (out of range issue). Thanks.